# How to get LIKE button url from Facebook webpage

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

I would like to synchronize LIKE buttons on Facebook with other webpage. Simply after I post on FB some article/video, there is a LIKE button. How do I get url of it, so I could add it to that other webpage with same article/video? I would like to archieve when somebody click LIKE button on FB or that webpage, they will be counted to the same list.

**Example:**
What URL I need to use to create a LIKE button, that would add people to this list:
http://www.facebook.com/browse/likes?id=386314241455183

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to put a like button on your webpage that syncs with the corresponding facebook page. Check this link :

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Scroll down the page, and go to Step1 ..
Enter the URL of your facebook page (eg : https://www.facebook.com/playbraindead)  in the widget and click submit, it will give you the code (HTML,IFRAME etc) which you can add to your webpage and the likebox will sync!

Comment: No,... I would like to get url to LIKE button of specific article on FB,.... your metod just get a LIKE count for the whole page. I make a screen about specific example: http://i48.tinypic.com/k69gy.jpg